# My WP7 Client application does not call the wcf on IIS

Tags: wcf, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, iis-7

Hi i have a WP7 application that calls a wcf who runs with membership api in a .net project.
I have added the service reference to my wcf in my application. And i can access this service in my browser with no problem.

I have now used Fiddler to track what is happening and when i call the service from my application fiddler is not picking up ANYTHING. But when i access this service manually through browser fiddle catches the traffic.

What is the problem?
The error message VS 2010 give me is

> There was no endpoint listening at https://localhost/MyApp/Authentication.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: Are you running the app on a phone or the emulator?

Comment: Can you access the wsdl with the wp7 browser? If there is a certificate error the service call wont work. You have to install it in the emulator first. Also wshttpbinding is notpossible in wp7 you need to use basichttpbindig or another supported binding

Comment: Are you hosting the service on port 80? Could your default Web site be listening on this port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my self-signed certificate didn't have the same name as the hostname of my computer.

I added a hostname instead of using localhost and then i also changed the name of my selfsigned certificate to the same name as my hostname.

https://myhostname/nameofwcf.svc
self signed certificate name = myhostname

Answer (score 0):

Your error report says you are trying to run SSL locally (by way of HTTPS). How have you set up a local certificate? Is that certificate from a root CA trusted by the phone (and not a test certificate)?